# Swift Migration - Setting up existing framework to work with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

In my project i have following setup

- Library Project - which builds to OSX framework
- Main Project - OSX application

So library project is build into the framework, and main project uses that private framework.
Headers on library are all in project group, application uses header_search_paths setting to find the headers.

Now I'm trying to make the lib work nicely with swift (get the suggestions), and to do that I need to make the framework build into the *module*.

So I am moving the header files from *project* to *public* group. But problem now is that the headers are shipped with app, but I would like them to be not visible (as it's private framework).

Is there way to make the headers private when i ship the app, but have the module build so that i get the suggestions from swift ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a top most header file (for example yourProject.h) which is visible and import all your header files that you want hidden into it. Then bridge that header file in your Swift project-Bridging-Header.h.